# Passing initial data in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that injects an iframe to the page and calls my site which is managed with spring mvc. I build the initial url that includes data that i get from certain content scripts so this data is available to me only when i open my extension. My scenario is this:

1. The user opens the extension which inejcts an iframe with a url
   to my site. (http://www.mysite.com/extension)
2. if the user is logged in, my system handles the request with controller "A" and returns the main view.
3. if the user is not logged in my system then i refer him to the login view. the action of the form in the login view is with an addition /login (http://www.mysite.com/extension/login) so the same controller "A" can handle the request but with a different request mapping (different function). if the user successfully logs in then he will be referred to the main view.

the problem is that if the user is not logged in then i will "lose" the data i initially got from the first request. Is there an elegant way to save the data for the first request in the session so i can access it? or any other way?

Comment: The answer is in the question, isn't it? You could also use hidden fields.

Comment: Also, you can make use of chrome.storage.local which is local to chrome extension or HTML5 localstorage.

Comment: @JBNizet - The issue is that the login and main are different jsps. i don't want to handle each request and implicitly assign the hidden input values.

Comment: @Cody - in my injected iframe i dont have access the the chrome API so the chrome.storage.local is out. about html5, im not that familiar yet with it so i would prefer not to use it as my first option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did is that i made an interceptor that pushes the values to the session object. I don't think that this is an elegant solution but it did the job. If anyone has a better solution, i would like to hear it. Thanks